# How to raise a method in “Form1” as an event in another class "DSCapture”

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

My requirement here is for “FrameSaved” event in DSCapture class to call the _cam_FrameSaved(Bitmap capImage, string imgPath). But I have two challenges which are;

1. FrameSaved event handler returning null.
2. FramSaved event handler not calling the method in Form1.cs

My Code:

**DSCapture**

```
public class DSCamCapture
{
    public event FrameSavedEventHandler FrameSaved;
    public delegate void FrameSavedEventHandler(Bitmap capImage, string imgPath);

    public void SaveCurrentFrame(string strFileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat iFormat)
        {
            ImagePathName = strFileName;
            ImgFormat = iFormat;
            saveImage = true;
            tmrSaved = new Timer();
            tmrSaved.Interval = 10;
            tmrSaved.Enabled = true;
            tmrSaved.Tick += new EventHandler(tmrSaved_Tick);
            tmrSaved.Start();
            //TmrSaved.Start();
        }

        private void tmrSaved_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!saveImage)
            {
                tmrSaved.Stop();
                capturedPic.Save(ImagePathName, ImgFormat);

                if (FrameSaved != null)
                {
                    FrameSaved(capturedPic, ImagePathName);
                }

            }
        }
}
```

**Form1.CS**

```
private void _cam_FrameSaved(System.Drawing.Bitmap capImage, string imgPath)
        {
            pictureBox2.Image = new Bitmap(capImage);
            label3.Text = "Saved As - " + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(imgPath);
            label4.Text = "Image Size - " + pictureBox2.Image.Size.ToString();
        }
```

But this works well in VB.NET as the method in form1.cs handles DSCapture.FrameSaved as shown below:

**VB.NET**

```
Private Sub cam_FrameSaved(ByVal capImage As System.Drawing.Bitmap, ByVal imgPath As String) Handles cam.FrameSaved
        PictureBox2.Image = New Bitmap(capImage)
        Label2.Text = "Saved As - " & IO.Path.GetFileName(imgPath)
        Label3.Text = "Image Size - " & PictureBox2.Image.Size.ToString
    End Sub
```

How do I get this to work in c#?

Comment: `_cam_FrameSaved` is subscribed to the event? check the properties window under events tab, if `cam` is a control.

Comment: Thanks for replying Mathew. cam was declared like thus in the vb code;  Private WithEvents cam As New DSCapture

Comment: What about C#? How is cam declared in it? Its C# where you want help with, right?

Comment: Yes Mathew. I declared it thus;                                       private DSCapture cam = new DSCapture();                                   I apologise for the late response. I stepped out of my desk for a while.

Comment: And equivalent to `VB.net`'s `Handles cam.FrameSaved`, you should write `cam.FrameSaved+=_cam_FrameSaved` after the declaration so that event get subscribed. Have done that?

Comment: Don't know where to add that bit of code in Form1.cs file. Actually if you look at the `tmrSaved_Tick` event in the `DSCapture` class, `FrameSaved(capturedPic, ImagePathName);` is called which is supposed to call the method `_cam_FrameSaved` in the Form1.cs class. But that's not happening in my code.

Comment: Add that line under the `InitializeComponent()` call in constructor.

Comment: Application Completed!!! You are a genius. You just made me finish with this thing. It worked like magic. I really appreciate the help. Hey How do I mark this as an answer by the way? I'm so grateful!

Comment: You cannot mark a comment as an answer, and glad to know I was able to help. Have fun coding.

Comment: Oh my! Thanks all the same. I hope our paths cross again